# Poll multiple repositories and trigger build if either of the repo is changed

Tags: jenkins, version-control, polling

I have multiple repositories in Subversion, I want to poll all these repositories in jenkins single job and trigger the build even if the either of them is changed.

I have tried with multibranch SCM plugin but it goes into infinite loop of triggering the build.

Comment: What is the build you want to trigger? Is it related to the multiple repositories? Would  you elaborate please?

Comment: No it is not related to multiple repositories. I only want to detect the change. Once the change has been detected, I have the entire flow set. for example I will proceed to execute some shell scripts.

Comment: I can easily imagine how to achieve this with multiple jobs in jenkins. Since you want to achieve these in one single job. Idk how to achieve this.

Comment: With multiple jobs I can do it. Can we write Jenkinsfile to poll multiple SCMs?